# Can an ICriteria return an IDictionary instead of a List<DTO>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Currently I can get this `SetResultTransformer` method to return a List of some arbitrary kind of DTO as follows:

```
var result = _session.CreateCriteria<Company>()
    .Add(Restrictions.In(groupCompanyInfo, (int[])groups.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToArray()))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(groupCompanyInfo), "CompanyInfoGroupID")
        .Add(Projections.RowCount(), "TotalNumberOfCompanies"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<SomeDTO>())
    .List<SomeDTO>();
```

where SomeDTO is defined as:

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int CountOfCompaniesInGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I think it's a little bit of an overkill having to create a type specifically to take the data out of this query though. Ideally, I could use a `IDictionary<int,int>`, because built into the framework. As it stands though, it seems I can return a List.

I thought I could throw a sneaky `KeyValuePair<int,int>` into the `SetResultsTransformer`, like this:

```
var result = _session.CreateCriteria<Company>()
    .Add(Restrictions.In(groupCompanyInfo, (int[])groups.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToArray()))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(groupCompanyInfo))
        .Add(Projections.RowCount())) // note, I removed the aliases
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<KeyValuePair<int, int>>())
    .List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
```

but `result` is just an empty KeyValuePair. Is there any way for me to do this, or do I need the DTO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a client-side Linq projection. I do this all the time:

```
var result = _session.CreateCriteria...
             .List<object[]>
             .ToDictionary(x => (int)x[0], x => (int)x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = _session.CreateCriteria<Company>()
    .Add(Restrictions.In(groupCompanyInfo, (int[])groups.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToArray()))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(groupCompanyInfo))
        .Add(Projections.RowCount())) // note, I removed the aliases
    .List();
```

This should return `IList<object[]>` :)